# CSS overflow-x hidden and overflow-y visible

Tags: jquery, css, overflow

I have read this SO Post: [css overflow-x visible and overflow-y hidden causes scroll bar.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causes-scroll-bar)

Also I have gone through: http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html

I want to achieve something as follows:

[image: Overflow]

When I tried using following code:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: visible;
```

It shows something like following result:
[image: Overflow 2]
I dont want the scroll bar to appear.

Does Jquery has any solution for it?

Comment: Ha, that last line was golden.

Comment: As you have seen the solution will be done by CSS not by jQuery. If you want to let jQuery do it for you, you will still have to understand the CSS rules for it to set the right code. As far as i know, there is no standard property in jQuery to solve this.

Comment: @GrantThomas I thought this question was pretty clear.

Comment: @BillyMathews Without pictures? In essence, perhaps, but the desired result is invisible to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with CSS like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper{
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}
.inner{
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Now your `.wrapper` div will have `overflow: visible;` but your `.inner` div will never overflow because it has a maximum width of 100% of the wrapper div. Note that your wrapper must have an explicitly defined width.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7y2cb/) is a working jsFiddle

Comment: I used these styles inside of a `position: fixed` sidebar div and added `overflow-y: scroll;` to the `.wrapper` and I could scroll up and down in the fixed div **AND** have `overflow-x` because tooltips were spilling out the side a bit.

Comment: it works with block or inline blocks. With float or absolute elements (like dropdown menu) it does not works. I have a scroll on y part

Comment: This still causes scrolling under a certain `line-height` threshold (which can be dictated by design).

Answer (score 6):

**CSS:**

```
.class-div {
   overflow-x: clip;
   overflow-y: visible;
}
```

The thing with clip is, it restricts all scrolling, even programmatic ones.

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: clip is not supported in safari

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if you need something like this with jQuery:

```
$('.horiz').width($('.container').width());
```

where `.horiz` is the horizontal bar and set the width of it to the width of the `.container` which holds the elements.

With CSS:

HTML Markup

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='horiz'></div>
    <div class='vert'></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .container {
    width:320px;
    height:320px;
    border:solid 5px green;
    overflow-x: hidden;
 }
 .horiz{
    width:500px;
    height:30px;
    background:red;
 }
 .vert{
    width:30px;
    height:500px;
    background:yellow;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:30px;
 }
```

and output of it:
[Check the Output](http://jsfiddle.net/4zp6e20c/)