# Negative margin element clipped outside of div only in one case?

Tags: html, css

I have given a small amount (`-7px`) negative margin to a div to align the text with an image next to it.

The divs have some different sizes according to a few media queries. Everything works fine except in the largest size which, for some reason, adds a small scrollbar and the negative margin is suddenly clipped.

I have no idea why this is happening?

Even adding height to the parent doesn't help and the scrollbar still appears for some reason?

For the life of me I can't recreate it in jsbin either, so I'm wondering if anyone had any tips on what could be causing the sudden appearance of a scrollbar/clipping?

**EDIT**

Apologies for the delay, took a while to strip out all the extraneous content but here is a working test that demonstrates the issue.

If you 'zoom out' or make the window very large, you can see the heading clipping suddenly. Forcing `overflow: visible` also does nothing. Definitely something odd is happening that is causing the scrollbar to suddenly appear too.

Here is a video that demonstrates the issue. My browser is zoomed out to 75% to simulate a larger screen. I am using Chrome 30.0.1599.22 on Mountain Lion.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant parts of your html/css that will allow us to see the problem?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Hi, I added more information to the question with some example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question:

> what could be causing the sudden appearance of a scrollbar/clipping?

It's caused by this CSS:

```
body.catalog-product-view .col-center {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 1800px !important;
}
```

And to be exact, it's caused by `overflow-x: hidden;`

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6433475/206614), W3C spec says:

> The computed values of ‘overflow-x’ and ‘overflow-y’ are the same as
>   their specified values, except that some combinations with ‘visible’
>   are not possible: if one is specified as ‘visible’ and the other is
>   ‘scroll’ or ‘auto’, then ‘visible’ is set to ‘auto’.

Here are possible solutions: [CSS overflow-x hidden and overflow-y visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970937/css-overflow-x-hidden-and-overflow-y-visible)
However, they didn't seem to work when I tried them with your code.

Comment: Ok, this was indeed the problem. Never knew it wasn't possible to combine the two. Very useful information thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Some example html/css would help us answer your question, but if the scrollbar is causing the negative margin to be clipped, why not just hide the overflow on the div to prevent the scrollbar from rendering?

```
div
   {
   overflow-y:hidden;
   }
```

Comment: I believe overflow hidden will force things to be clipped, whereas 'visible' should be the default behaviour that prevents clipping. Declaring 'visible' also doesn't seem to work for some reason though.

Answer (score 0):

waffl.

SO, here is the root of your bug =)

```
@media (min-width: 2088px)
body.catalog-product-view .col-center {
    overflow-x: hidden; /* this makes scroll visible and the text being cutted */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in CSS:

```
body { max-width: 200%;
}

div { width: 170%; }
```

If you define the width in percent values everything will be adjustable.