# overflow x: hidden causes vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, css

My problem is that when I define `overflow-x:hidden`, it creates an unwanted scrollbar.

I am trying to achieve something similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970937/css-overflow-x-hidden-and-overflow-y-visible).

I have tried the solution suggested there but that didn't work. Below is my code:

**CSS and HTML:**

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.menu_container {
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #607D8B;
  width: 20%;
  height: 30px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


.submenu {
  background: #E0E0E0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
}

.menu_list {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="menu_container">
      <div class="menu_list" align="left">
        Menu 1 Menu2 Menu 3
      </div>
      <div class="submenu">
        sub
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amgowano/zu7nrupq/2/) link.

Comment: The question you linked to talks about a scroll bar, which is not present on your JSfiddle. What exactly did you want your result to be?

Comment: What didn't work exactly?

Comment: The question you linked to talks about removing a scroll bar. Your question is not clear what you want as an end result. Please clarify what you want your end result to be

Comment: The end result that I want is explained in the question I linked: "Hiding content that has overflowed in the x-direction while keeping content that has overflown in the y-direction visible"

I have also updated my JSFiddle to show the failure.

@BenRondeau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways to achieve your goal:

**1. Set *height* of *.menu_container* to *auto***

HTML stays as it was, here is the CSS:

```
.wrapper {
margin-top: 50px;
}

.menu_container {
color: #333;
text-align: center;
padding: 1em;
background: #607D8B;
width: 20%;
height: auto; /* NEW */
overflow-x:hidden;
}

.submenu {
background: #E0E0E0;
height: 100px;
width: 50px;
display: none; /* I added this to show the effect when .submenu is invoked */
}

.menu_container:hover .submenu {
display: block; /* I added this to show the effect when .submenu is invoked */
}

.menu_list {
width: 300px;
}
```

Just hover over *.menu_container*: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zu7nrupq/7/)

This solution will make .menu_container grow, so the rest of the content is pushed down when *.submenu* is shown.

---

**2. Wrap *.submenu* in a seperate DIV and position it *absolute***

With this method, the .menu_container will not grow, so the following content stays where it is.

HTML:

```
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="submenu_container"> <!-- NEW -->
   <div class="menu_container">
    <div class="menu_list" align="left">
     Menu 1 Menu2 Menu 3
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="submenu">
    sub
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
  .wrapper {
   margin-top: 50px;
  }

  .menu_container {
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #607D8B;
  width: 20%;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  }

  .submenu_container { /* NEW */
  position: relative;
  }

 .submenu {
 background: #E0E0E0;
 height: 100px;
 width: 50px;
 position: absolute; /* NEW */
 left: 20px; /* Adjust to your needs */
 top: 40px; /* Adjust to your needs */
 }

 .menu_list {
 width: 300px;
 }
```

See the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zu7nrupq/19/)

Comment: This is PERFECT! Thanks @zork media. Sadly I can't upvote the answer since I have reputation that is less than 15. I will do so the moment I reach that reputation level. 

Thanks once again.

Comment: Glad to hear it. By the way: As the one who asked you don't have to vote up an answer. You can set the checkmark beneath the voting arrows to accept an answer as "correct". This will also tell Stackoverflow that the issue is closed and you've got a sufficient answer to your question.

Comment: In my particular case, when using `height:auto`, I had to change `overflow-x:hidden` by simply `overflow:hidden` to get rid of the annoying vertical scroll bar.

Answer (score 6):

`overflow-x: clip;` did actually solve this problem for me.

`clip`:
[...] The difference between clip and hidden is that the clip keyword also forbids all scrolling, including programmatic scrolling. [...]

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: This should be updated as the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

You could either add `html {overflow-y:hidden}` as well to your CSS or add `html {height:100%;}` to remove the y-scrollbar ( or thats atleast what I think you want to accomplish).

Adding `html {overflow-y:hidden}` would do that exact same thing as overflow-x but removes the y scroll bar. This maybe useful for what you are trying to accomplish, but its downside is that it **hides all content** that extends past 100% height of the browser.

Adding `html {height:100%;}` to your CSS would tell the browser that the webpage is exactly 100% of the browser size. This will move all of the content inwards so it fits all on the page (unless positioning is defined by pixels rather than percents). The downside to this method is that pushing all the content inwards may give you different results on different browsers and sizes.

Overall, I say you just keep the scroll bar, it will save you a lot of time in positioning and it just constricts your page.

Comment: Thanks for the response @ShaunLoftin. I actually want to have the content in the y direction visible. Wouldn't {overflow-y: hidden} achieve the opposite of this?

Also the reason why I want the y content to be visible is this: Imagine a situation where "Menu1", "Menu2" and "Menu3" are menu items on a navigation bar and "sub" is a pop-up menu that shows up once the user clicks "Menu 1". For a better user experience I want the div with "sub" to show up without scroll bars.

Comment: Then use the height method as I said and media queries to define your page based on browser sizes.