# CSS overflow-y: visible, overflow-x: hidden

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, overflow, slick.js

I have read this [CSS overflow-x hidden and overflow-y visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970937/css-overflow-x-hidden-and-overflow-y-visible) (and a lot of other posts) but i can't get this to work in my specific case.

I'm using ths [slick-slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and want to add dropdown-navigation. so i have to use a special markup.

The dropdown should overflow the slider.

I recreated the problem in the [`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/bejg1nqq/1/)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Setting overflow-x or overflow-y to hidden causes the other to be treated as if it has a value of auto. So slick-slider adds a scrollbar for any overflow in the y direction.

You can normally get around this by adding position: absolute. However, absolute positioning is based on the closest parent element with relative positioning. In this case, that's slick-slide, which is a child of slick-slider. As a result the dropdown is still positioned inside of slick-slider and doesn't overflow.

To resolve the issue remove position: relative from all classes that currently have it. I recommend adding position: relative to the wrapper class as well.

Comment: can you be more specific as to your answer here? adding position absolute to what?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `.slick-slider` class. If you set a little bigger `height` you can get past overflow, although I don't know why `overflow:visible` doesn't work.