# CSS Overflow-x Hidden and Overflow-y

Tags: css, overflow

I read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152490/css-overflow-y-visible-overflow-x-hidden) and didn't see if there is a solution to my issue.

I've created a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/katartgraphics/pen/gWyeyR) that shows this issue. I would like everything to the left and right (`overflow-x`) of the red border to be hidden, but keep the top and bottom (`overflow-y`) visible.

Any ideas on how to achieve this affect?

Answer (score 0):

update your .movie-posters style to this. And check if this is what you are looking for.

```
.movie-posters {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: 450px;
  margin: 6rem auto;
  border: 4px solid red;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

> i had to increase the height to make it look normal.

Comment: Thanks for the replay @Vilvan. So the way to make this visible is by expanding the parent element. I was hoping there was a cleaner way.